# SQL Server CASE With concatenating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation, case

I'm trying to create a column whose value is conditionally based on the already specified DB columns.

I have 6 columns:

```
ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnC
ColumnD
ColumnE
ColumnF
```

I have a query I use where I create this column `CUSTOMCODE` that will be determined based on the values of the 6 columns, and whichever one is null or not.

I've been using a `CASE` statement to try to generate the results I want, but there are a few rows that returning null. The logic for my case statement is as follows

```
CASE
    WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL and ColumnB IS NOT NULL
         THEN ColumnA + '-' + ColumnC + '-' + ColumnD + '-' + ColumnB
    WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL  and ColumnB IS NULL
         THEN ColumnA + '-' + ColumnC + '-' + ColumnD
    WHEN ColumnE IS NOT NULL
         THEN ColumnE + '-' + ColumnF
END AS CUSTOMCODE
```

Note for the data in this database, in this example ColumnB is NULL for every row.

When this query runs, for the  first row where `ColumnA, ColumnC, and ColumnD` are non-null it returns the first case properly, and CUSTOMCODE results in a non-null value.

For the second row, where the same `ColumnA, ColumnC, and ColumnD` are also not null, it returns a NULL value for CUSTOMCODE, and I'm not sure why.

And the way our backend is structured and how data comes in, then if those 3 columns are null then `ColumnE and ColumnF are not null`, however for rows where that is the case, it also results in CUSTOMCODE being NULL.

Is there something I'm missing in the CASE Statement, or do I need to restructure it or do something else?

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way here. [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: I'll work on the sample data. The real data and environment exist on a private sensitive network so I had to generalize as much as possible. I'll re-edit with more details to give more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing seems to be to wrap them all in `IS NULL`

```
select isnull(ColumnA,'') + isnull(ColumnB,'') + isnull(ColumnC,'') ...etc
```

If that isn't what you really want, you need to remember that the `CASE` statement will exit once the first condition is me. Thus, the order of your `CASE` matters.

For example, the last `CASE`, `WHEN ColumnE IS NOT NULL` *could* never be met because in the first two `CASE` this could also be `TRUE`.

> Note for the data in this database, in this example ColumnB is NULL
>   for every row.

If this is true, then the third `CASE` will never happen if `ColumnA` isn't `NULL` since the second `CASE` is `WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL  and ColumnB IS NULL`.

> For the second row, where the same ColumnA, ColumnC, and ColumnD are also not null, it returns a NULL value for CUSTOMCODE, and I'm not sure why.

This definitly wouldn't happen with the code you supplied. But, it's important to understand that `NULL` and an *empty space* is not the same thing. i.e. `select 'true' where NULL = ''` will never be true.

Lastly, remember that anything + `NULL` = `NULL`. i.e. `select 1 + NULL` would return `NULL`

Comment: I eventually ended up changing the order of my CASE statement which helped out a lot. I additionally added the IsNull to the columns which helped ensure that I wasn't concatenating null columns. This answer helped out the best. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @OscarMcCullough

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your logic, but as far as I can see, you're not checking `NULL` value for the columns `ColumnC`,`ColumnD` and `ColumnF`, if one of these is `NULL`, your field `CUSTOMCODE` will be `NULL`

Try this:

```
CASE
    WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL and ColumnB IS NOT NULL
        THEN ColumnA + '-' + ISNULL(ColumnC, '') + '-' + ISNULL(ColumnD, '') + '-' + ColumnB
    WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL  and ColumnB IS NULL
        THEN ColumnA + '-' + ISNULL(ColumnC, '') + '-' + ISNULL(ColumnD, '')
    WHEN ColumnE IS NOT NULL
        THEN ColumnE + '-' + ISNULL(ColumnF, '')
END AS CUSTOMCODE
```

Although I would recommend checking the logic of your script, maybe you could do the same only with [`ISNULL()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)(?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select stuff( coalesce('-' + columna, '') +
              coalesce('-' + columnb, '') +
              coalesce('-' + columnc, '') +
              coalesce('-' + columnd, '') +
              coalesce('-' + columne, '') +
              coalesce('-' + columnf, ''), 1, 1, ''
             ) as concatenated_together_with_hyphen
```

This is the equivalent of `concat_ws()` in other databases.